# How make a javascript for-loop or function to push the following number pattern to an array

Tags: javascript

I wonder if anyone could show me a way of creating a loop or function that would create the following array pattern:

```
let array = [0,0,100,100,-100,-100,100,100,-100,-100]
```

Comment: What even is the pattern?

Comment: The pattern is: two first elements are 0 and then alteration of pairs 100 and -100. `let array = [0, 0]; for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) { const n = 100 * (i % 2 === 0 ? -1 : 1); array.push(n, n) }`.

Comment: That answered my question thank you. Would you have the time to explain the syntax please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a pattern which changes the sign each 2nd index and treat the first two items different.

```js
var array = Array.from(
        { length: 10 },
        (v => (_, i) => (i >> 1 && [v, -v][i >> 1 & 1]))(-100)
    );

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but my javascript is not good enough to understand the syntax.